# Convert 3d Numpy array to 2d

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 3d numpy array of following form:

```
array([[[ 1.,  5.,  4.],
    [ 1.,  5.,  4.],
    [ 1.,  2.,  4.]],

   [[ 3.,  6.,  4.],
    [ 6.,  6.,  4.],
    [ 6.,  6.,  4.]]])
```

Is there a efficient way to convert it to a 2d array of form:

```
array([[1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 2, 4, 4, 4],
   [3, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 4, 4, 4]])
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
In [54]: arr = np.array([[[ 1.,  5.,  4.],
                         [ 1.,  5.,  4.],
                         [ 1.,  2.,  4.]],

                        [[ 3.,  6.,  4.],
                         [ 6.,  6.,  4.],
                         [ 6.,  6.,  4.]]])

In [61]: arr.reshape((arr.shape[0], -1), order='F')
Out[61]: 
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  5.,  5.,  2.,  4.,  4.,  4.],
       [ 3.,  6.,  6.,  6.,  6.,  6.,  4.,  4.,  4.]])
```

---

The array `arr` has shape `(2, 3, 3)`. We wish to keep the first axis of length 2, and  flatten the two axes of length 3.

If we call [`arr.reshape(h, w)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) then NumPy will attempt to reshape `arr` to shape `(h, w)`. If we call `arr.reshape(h, -1)` then NumPy will replace the `-1` with whatever integer is needed for the reshape to make sense -- in this case, `arr.size/h`.

Hence,

```
In [63]: arr.reshape((arr.shape[0], -1))
Out[63]: 
array([[ 1.,  5.,  4.,  1.,  5.,  4.,  1.,  2.,  4.],
       [ 3.,  6.,  4.,  6.,  6.,  4.,  6.,  6.,  4.]])
```

This is almost what we want, but notice that the values in each subarray, such as

```
[[ 1.,  5.,  4.],
[ 1.,  5.,  4.],
[ 1.,  2.,  4.]]
```

are being traversed by marching from left to right before going down to the next row.
We want to march down the rows before going on to the next column.
To achieve that, use `order='F'`.

Usually the elements in a NumPy array are visited in `C-order` -- where the last index moves fastest. If we visit the elements in `F-order` then the first index moves fastest. Since in a 2D array of shape `(h, w)`, the first axis is associated with the rows and the last axis the columns, traversing the array in `F-order` marches down each row before moving on to the next column.

Comment: Thanks a lot @unutbu! Can you explain your code a little bit? I don't quite understand how numpy reshape works.