# Training a SVM Classifier on pair of Embeddings, generating error

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, neural-network, svm

For each person in my dataset, I have a labelled collection of a pair of images from their different profiles .For person A, data looks like:

PersonA FacebookImage InstagramImage 0  (0 is the label, if both images belong to person A)

I have generated embeddings(as a numpy array) for each image of length 128 and concatenated them to a numpy array as pair.

The main idea is to train the classifier such that two embeddings of images belonging to same person are similar.

The training data looks similar to:

```
[[[0 3 4..............   [0 1 .........
   .............          ............
   .................      .............
   .................128]  .........128]]...................]]]
```

and the training labels data looks like:

```
[0,1,1,0,0,.........]
```

where each pair is pair of embeddings of same person. I am trying to train these embeddings on a SVM classifier,using the code:

`clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=1).fit(X_train, y_train)`
but I am encountered with an error message:

```
Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2.
```

How can I resolve this error?

The shape of my training set is (2000,2,128) and the shape of each embedding is (128,)

Comment: What is the current shape of the numpy array?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert 3d Numpy array to 2d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37500804/convert-3d-numpy-array-to-2d)

Comment: can you give the shape of this array?

Comment: Also, look into this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33162871/python-scikit-learn-svm-classifier-valueerror-found-array-with-dim-3-expected/35005672

Comment: @kmario23  The shape of my training array if (2583,2,128).

Comment: @Jayanth what's the expected shape of the 2D array for your SVM classifier?

Comment: @kmario23 I have rephrased the question. Can you please take a look at this?